# Context.obtainStyledAttributes() warning

Tags: android, android-widget, android-theme

I just wasted 3 hours on this issue, so I hope this will save somebody some time.

```
public TypedArray obtainStyledAttributes (AttributeSet set, int[] attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

The second argument `attrs` **MUST** contain the attribute identifiers in a strictly increasing order, otherwise the attribute value won't get resolved and the call will silently fail as if the attribute did not exist.

This is no where documented that I can see and it took me forever to figure out what was going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This type of post is encouraged around here, just one thing: [Please keep it in the form of question and answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). So please post a question and an answer. You can accept your own answer later and might even earn a shiny *self-learner* badge *(if you care for those :P)*.